# Tengo que obtener el mensaje de error pero no me deja utilizarlo

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, try-catch

Estoy realizando un script de SQL Server en el cual tras realizar **BULK INSERT** me tiene que dar un mensaje de error o de éxito si no ha habido errores. Este es el script un poco editado.

```sql
USE Server;
TRUNCATE TABLE librosventas;
BEGIN TRY
    BULK INSERT librosventas
    FROM 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\CSV\librosventas.csv'
    WITH (FIRSTROW= 1, FIELDTERMINATOR = '|', ROWTERMINATOR= '0x0a')
    --0x0a SUSTITUYE /n
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF ERROR_MESSAGE() IS NULL
        BEGIN
        INSERT INTO LogTable (error_msj) VALUES ('Sucess')
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
        INSERT INTO LogTable (error_msj) VALUES (ERROR_MESSAGE())
        END
END CATCH;
GO
SELECT * FROM LogTable
```

El script en sí funciona, el problema se encuentra que al realizar la última línea del script `SELECT * FROM LogTable` no aparece ni "Success" ni un error (Aunque en este caso no hay error, pero sí debería aparecer Success en la tabla). ¿Hay algo que se me escapa? Porque en varias preguntas parecidas me aparecen scripts parecidos y que funcionan.

Gracias de antemano.
Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por la linea de Begin Catch solo pasa, si ocurre una excepción en el bloque desde Begin Try hasta End Try. Por tanto el insert into LogTable solo lo ejecutaría, si hubiera algún problema.

```
USE Server;
GO
TRUNCATE TABLE librosventas;
BEGIN TRY
    BULK INSERT librosventas
    FROM 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\CSV\librosventas.csv'
    WITH (FIRSTROW= 1, FIELDTERMINATOR = '|', ROWTERMINATOR= '0x0a')
    --0x0a SUSTITUYE /n

    INSERT INTO LogTable (error_msj) VALUES ('Sucess')
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
        INSERT INTO LogTable (error_msj) VALUES (ERROR_MESSAGE())

END CATCH;
GO
SELECT * FROM LogTable;
```

[try catch Sql Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: ¡WOW! Ahora sí. Muchísimas gracias. No había entendido bien TRY y CATCH. Muchas gracias.